# table of contents page number alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, alignment

I have some problems with the page number alignment in the table of contents of my dissertation. The screenshots of the 3 specific points are shown below. As you can observe

- the page number related to 4.4.3 is not aligned correctly.
- the text related to Part II is not fitted well and the associated page number is also not aligned correctly.
- Last point, similar to previous one, one appendix line is also not fitted correctly and extends into the page margins and giving problems. There is also the page number alignment problem with this section title.

I copied my dissertation class template here for a check:

https://pastebin.com/yYEbewQY

which is the template of Delft University of Technology in the Netherlands. I slightly modified it without changing the essential components since I don't have much experience with modifying/generating class file.

Any help is appreciated on this alignment and fitting to the margins issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please create a small minimal example and add this cod directly into your question? Links to external sites might expire.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using a `.cls` provided by your university and perhaps this is how they want it to look (in general universities are not renowned for their typographic requirements and skills). If it is not then gently point out the problem to the proper authorities, but being careful not to get on the wrong side of them. GOM